# Unable to load index to elasticsearch using logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm Unable to load index to elasticsearch using logstash. The follwing are my logstash.conf settings. To me config settings seems fine. Please help if I'm missing something.

Assume that Logstash & elastic search services are running fine.

```html
input { 
 file {
   type => "IISLog"
   path => "C:/inetpub/logs/LogFiles/W3SVC1/u_ex140930.log"
   start_postition => "beginning"
 }
}

output {
  stdout { debug => true debug_format => "ruby"}
  elasticsearch_http {
        host => "localhost"
        port => 9200
  protocol => "http"
  index => "iislogs2"
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you get anything on stdout? Is there something interesting in the Logstash logs? What if you start Logstash with `--verbose` or even `--debug`?

Comment: I wouldn't "assume that [everything] is running fine.  There are a lot of moving pieces!  Here's a guide to diagnosing ELK issues: http://svops.com/blog/?p=26

Answer (score 0):

You can start with checking the following:

1. Check the logstash log file for errors.
2. Run the following command:`telnet localhost 9200` and verify you are able to connect.
3. Check elasticsearch log files for errors.